# Calculating dates in excel

Tags: date, if-statement, excel-formula, numbers

[image]

I want to count the dates. 1 date = 1, 2 dates = 2... 
I have 2 dates and I want to prepare a formula if I have 2 dates, then this is total 2.

Comment: You'd want to count your dates then - some kind of `COUNT` formula should do it.

Comment: I have two question.  1) what does Eva and Tajda translate to in english?  2) 
 What date format is 4.9.?  Is that an actual date?  does it change format if you change the cell format from general to date, or is it text?  `=istext(A1)` where A1 is the cell with 4.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the range references to suit your data.

```
=COUNTA(C2:G2)
```

Where C2:G2 is your first row under datum.  This equation will count the number of non blank cells.

[image]

If 4.9. is a number an not text, then you could also use

```
=COUNT(C2:G2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Excel you could create a new column that checks if the cell is a date by doing `=ISERROR(DAY(A1))`.
If it is a date the formula will return FALSE.

Then simply count all the cells with FALSE by doing `=COUNTIF(B1:B10;FALSE)`
Here B1:B10 should be replaced with the cellrange of your new column that holds the true or false values

Comment: Thanks for this.. I have tried, but I have it a little bit complicated :   
Eva  5.9.  17.9. 
Tajda 4.9.  12.9. 17.9. 26.9.  : for first row I need total 2 as there are 2 dates, and second one 4.. there is also a problem as there is some cells empty

Comment: @PetraMarinšek edit your question, type in the information in plain text as example data.  make it look right when you type it out.  Do not worry if it does not show correctly, we can edit that part for you if we can see how it was typed out in what would look like a table.